# create column in r by adding all the characters in another column

Tags: r, count

I have a column called features and each row has the following entries

```
ABS, AM/FM Radio, Air Bags, Air Conditioning, CD Player
ABS, AM/FM Radio, Air Bags, Air Conditioning
ABS, AM/FM Radio, Air Bags
```

what  want to do is create a column called Number of features that would give the result

```
5
4
3
```

Comment: pleae add sample data using `dput()`

Comment: I am unware of the dput() function

Comment: try `?dput()` for more information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your data frame looks like this:

```r
df <- data.frame(col  = c("ABS, AM/FM Radio, Air Bags, Air Conditioning, CD Player",
                          "ABS, AM/FM Radio, Air Bags, Air Conditioning",
                          "ABS, AM/FM Radio, Air Bags"))

df
#>                                                       col
#> 1 ABS, AM/FM Radio, Air Bags, Air Conditioning, CD Player
#> 2            ABS, AM/FM Radio, Air Bags, Air Conditioning
#> 3                              ABS, AM/FM Radio, Air Bags
```

Then you could do:

```r
df$items <- lengths(strsplit(df$col, ","))

df
#>                                                       col items
#> 1 ABS, AM/FM Radio, Air Bags, Air Conditioning, CD Player     5
#> 2            ABS, AM/FM Radio, Air Bags, Air Conditioning     4
#> 3                              ABS, AM/FM Radio, Air Bags     3
```

This works simply by counting the number of segments each row contains when you split the text strings at the commas. It will work as long as none of the item names themself contain commas.

Comment: May be `lengths` is faster `lengths(strsplit(df$col, ","))`